# Packets are not in the proper order with respect to DTS when using libx264 for video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp, x264

I'm trying to use the following command to transcode one stream to a different format and send it over to RTMP server for live streaming.

This is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -f mxg -i http://admin:meinsm@192.168.1.161:80/control/faststream.jpg?stream=MxPEG -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ac 1 -f flv -s 1024x768 rtmp://localhost:1340/big/test
```

Apparently, it decodes some frames and ends up with an error:

```
ffmpeg version 2.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May  7 2014 13:08:45 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC) 20140206 (prerelease)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --enable-avresample --enable-dxva2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-pic --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-swresample --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libavresample   1.  2.  0 /  1.  2.  0
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mxg, from 'http://admin:meinsm@192.168.1.161:80/control/faststream.jpg?stream=MxPEG':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1399552944.946674, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mxpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1024x768, 10 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
No pixel format specified, yuvj420p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] 264 - core 142 r2397 aff928d - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=10 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://localhost:1340/big/test':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuvj420p, 1024x768, q=-1--1, 1k tbn, 10 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mxpeg -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_alaw -> aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   23 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:06.45 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s    
frame=   25 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:07.06 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s    
frame=   27 fps= 16 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:07.66 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    
frame=   29 fps= 12 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:08.26 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    
frame=   31 fps= 11 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:08.84 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    
frame=   33 fps=9.3 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:09.45 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s    
frame=   35 fps=8.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:10.05 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s    
frame=   37 fps=7.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:10.65 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s    
frame=   39 fps=7.3 q=0.0 size=       5kB time=00:00:11.26 bitrate=   3.6kbits/s    
frame=   41 fps=6.9 q=0.0 size=      15kB time=00:00:11.86 bitrate=  10.2kbits/s    
[flv @ 0x1509ec0] Packets are not in the proper order with respect to DTS
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
[flv @ 0x1509ec0] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x1509ec0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame=   42 fps=3.9 q=21.0 Lsize=     179kB time=00:00:11.91 bitrate= 123.2kbits/s    
video:38kB audio:171kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -14.421207%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] frame I:1     Avg QP:11.92  size: 38627
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] frame P:11    Avg QP:14.66  size: 14503
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] frame B:30    Avg QP:18.54  size:  2310
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] consecutive B-frames:  2.4%  4.8%  7.1% 85.7%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] mb I  I16..4: 31.9% 60.7%  7.4%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] mb P  I16..4:  4.7% 28.3%  0.8%  P16..4: 17.7% 12.9% 15.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:20.1%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  1.8%  0.0%  B16..8: 32.8%  4.0%  2.1%  direct: 1.4%  skip:57.6%  L0:50.7% L1:47.0% BI: 2.2%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] 8x8 transform intra:80.0% inter:87.1%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 59.5% 0.6% 0.5% inter: 7.3% 0.1% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 20% 16%  8% 56%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 28% 30%  2%  4%  1%  9%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 41% 34% 11%  2%  4%  1%  5%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 97%  1%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:36.4% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] ref P L0: 55.3%  4.4% 22.7% 14.0%  3.6%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] ref B L0: 82.4% 14.7%  2.8%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] ref B L1: 88.9% 11.1%
[libx264 @ 0x150a4a0] kb/s:171.17
Conversion failed!
```

These are the crucial lines:

```
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   23 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:06.45 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s    
frame=   25 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:07.06 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s    
frame=   27 fps= 16 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:07.66 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    
frame=   29 fps= 12 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:08.26 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    
frame=   31 fps= 11 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:08.84 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    
frame=   33 fps=9.3 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:09.45 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s    
frame=   35 fps=8.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:10.05 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s    
frame=   37 fps=7.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:10.65 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s    
frame=   39 fps=7.3 q=0.0 size=       5kB time=00:00:11.26 bitrate=   3.6kbits/s    
frame=   41 fps=6.9 q=0.0 size=      15kB time=00:00:11.86 bitrate=  10.2kbits/s    
[flv @ 0x1509ec0] Packets are not in the proper order with respect to DTS
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
[flv @ 0x1509ec0] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x1509ec0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
```

What is wrong here, how do I overcome this?